# JSON as Dictionary with python how to use

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Im trying to play with a data source for learning purposes. I am trying to take data from public data source and deliver it to a small sqlite DB.

I have this json structure:

```
    [
 {
   "name": "Aachen",
   "id": 1,
   "nametype": "Valid",
   "recclass": "L5",
   "mass (g)": 21,
   "fall": "Fell",
   "year": "01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM",
   "reclat": 50.775,
   "reclong": 6.08333,
   "GeoLocation": "(50.775, 6.08333)"
 },
 {
   "name": "Aarhus",
   "id": 2,
   "nametype": "Valid",
   "recclass": "H6",
   "mass (g)": 720,
   "fall": "Fell",
   "year": "01/01/1951 12:00:00 AM",
   "reclat": 56.18333,
   "reclong": 10.23333,
   "GeoLocation": "(56.18333, 10.23333)"
 },]
```

so far I managed to work with the below code, but how do I read the data correctly?

this part doesnt work:

```
name = entry[0];
id = entry[1];
```

here is part of the code I use:

```
import json
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('rosterdb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Do some setup
cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Member;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Course;

CREATE TABLE User (
    id     INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name   TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Course (
    id     INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title  TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Member (
    user_id     INTEGER,
    course_id   INTEGER,
    role        INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, course_id)
)
''')

fname = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'meteorite.json'


str_data = open(fname).read()
json_data = json.loads(str_data)

for entry in json_data:

    name = entry[0];
    id = entry[1];

    print name, id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load json , you get json objects in a list. So you iterate that list using for loop

```
for item in json_data:
```

at this point item refers to json object not to list and you are trying to access list in you code by using

```
name = entry[0];
```

one more thing dont use (;) in python to end statement and you are using that

You need to get data from dictionary, It should be like this

```
for item in json_data:
    name=item.get('name')
    id=item.get('id')
```

Your code should be like this

```
import json
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('rosterdb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Do some setup
cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Member;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Course;

CREATE TABLE User (
    id     INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name   TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Course (
    id     INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title  TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Member (
    user_id     INTEGER,
    course_id   INTEGER,
    role        INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, course_id)
)
''')

fname = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'meteorite.json'


str_data = open(fname).read()
json_data = json.loads(str_data)

for entry in json_data:

    name=entry.get('name')
    id=entry.get('id')

    print name, id
```